# R- Iteratively combine consecutive elements of a character vector until an empty string element is reached

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a character vector made up of long strings (alphanumeric + special characters) such as the one described below.

```
txt <- c(
         "Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet", 
         "tenderloin. pariatur quis",
         "",
         "consequat pancetta jerky", 
         "porchetta non chuck exercitation",
         "laborum labore ball tip.",
         "",
         "",
         "Duis swine turkey kielbasa. Strip ",
         "steak ribeye laboris,"
        )
```

Output needed is

```
> txt
[1] "Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet tenderloin. pariatur quis"
[2] "consequat pancetta jerky porchetta non chuck exercitation laborum labore ball tip."
[3] "Duis swine turkey kielbasa. Strip steak ribeye laboris,"
```

Things to consider:
1. The empty string element/s act as linebreakers. They could be more than one consecutively.
2. On joining two elements together, a space needs to be added in between.

Comment: have been breaking my head over nested for, while and if loop/statements, but realize there might be a better way to do it, especially given the large amount of data at hand (80,000 elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of a plethora of ways to do this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

data_frame(txt=txt, grp=cumsum(txt=="")) %>% 
  group_by(grp) %>% 
  do(data_frame(joined=paste0(.$txt, collapse=" "))) %>% 
  mutate(joined=trimws(joined)) %>% 
  filter(joined != "") %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(joined) %>% 
  flatten_chr()
## [1] "Spicy jalapeno bacon ipsum dolor amet tenderloin. pariatur quis"                   
## [2] "consequat pancetta jerky porchetta non chuck exercitation laborum labore ball tip."
## [3] "Duis swine turkey kielbasa. Strip  steak ribeye laboris,"
```

Comment: My exact train of thought! Very nice

Comment: This is awesome..thanks! I'll spend the next hour trying to understand this!

Comment: Cool. The key thing to look at is what `txt=""` produces, then what `cumsum(txt=="")` produces. Don't hesitate to ask for clarification.